# The data is specific to my client app, and I want to ensure API accessibility without requiring other users to log in

Tags: laravel, flutter, security, oauth-2.0

I am working on a Flutter client app that retrieves data from a backend system developed with Laravel. The data is specific to my client app, and I want to ensure API accessibility without requiring other users to log in. Additionally, I want to avoid exposing my backend credentials.

Considering these requirements, what is the recommended approach for securing API access in this scenario? Are there specific best practices or strategies I should follow to ensure secure communication between my Flutter app and the Laravel backend?

I have considered storing API keys on the client side, but I am concerned about potential security risks. Is there a more secure alternative or additional measures I can implement to safeguard the API access without compromising the backend credentials?

I appreciate any guidance or insights on best practices for securing API access in a Flutter app that interacts with a Laravel backend in a scenario where user login is not required.

I tried the Laravel/passport OAuth system.

Comment: You can accept requests only from desired origins. Set it in config/cors.php and config/passport.php

Comment: In my case, I am developing Flutter app for mobile (iOS or Android), handling the origin for network requests might not be necessary as CORS restrictions typically apply to web applications running in browsers. @EHFShahab